# Print Version history in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

Is that possible to print out version history at Sharepoint 2010?
If possible, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get it right, but I used to press **CTRL+P** when the version history is open. The CSS is smart enough to render the version history without navigation elements and other unwanted content. You get a pretty clean table. Try is with a XPS/PDF printer to see what I mean.

But since my answer is extremly simple, I might have misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any OOTB solution. I'm suggest you need to use third party solution or make custom development. For example, [this tool](http://roxority.com/sharepoint-zen/export-to-csv-with-sharepoint-list-item-version-history-new.html) allow export all items with history

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# object model or PowerShell to generate a detailed version history report. Find the code snippets at:  [SharePoint Version History Report](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/versioning-size-report-for-sharepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to develop a new application page based on the original "versions.aspx" page, then I added some custom controls on the new page.

1. Go to "/Template/Layouts/versions.aspx" and copy this page into your desktop or another location.
   **Note: Please DO NOT modify the original versions.aspx page just copy it.**
2. Create an SP empty project on VS, and map the "Layouts" folder to the project
3. Add the page to the mapped folder (ie Layouts/CustomVersionHistoryPage/versions.aspx)
4. Modify the page as you want, I added the following controls:

   - [Fluid Text Resizer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/fluidtextresizer.htm) (from Dynamic Drive) to adjust the text size on this page
   - Button to print only the version history information, not the page background (you can achieve this with a JS function)

[image]

5. Create a "List Item Menu" (Custom Action) with SP Designer or Visual Studio, to the corresponding list, and add the following URL to navigate to your custom version history page:

> /_layouts/CustomVersionHistoryPage/Versions.aspx?list={ListId}&ID={ItemId}

[image]

Note: This solution works at Farm level, So you can add the same custom action to any lists on any site collection and it should work.